# How to read a method codes from another activity in my activity?

Tags: java, android, methods

I want to call a method from another activity in my activity. I tried this codes but my app is crashed! :

SecondActivity:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity
{


public void toast()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",50).show();
}

}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import com.mycompany.myapp.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SecondActivity s=new SecondActivity();
        s.toast();

    }
}
```

What the problem?! Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: please post the error

Comment: There is no  error. But when I play the app my app force closed!

Comment: check your logcat. It should display meaningful error there.

Comment: Activity classes need to go through the lifecycle (launch or intents) so just 'new'ing one probably means the 'getApplicationContext' call is failing.

Comment: LogCat is it: <run the app to see its log output>

Comment: Is there any other way to call the method in other activity?

Comment: You should see something like this https://www.google.com/search?q=logcat+android+studio&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJmdSt_sDhAhVf73MBHTcZC3QQ_AUIDigB&biw=1299&bih=620#imgrc=rFdjUXA898hJ8M:

Comment: You can't just create an instance of an Activity class like that. It will crash. You need to ask the system to create Activities for you. Although to be fair, if people were writing Android apps correctly, you'd never start a second Activity that resides in the same app's flow in an accessible way. We'd be swapping either Fragments, or Views, or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing the Java class and Activity. If you want to declare the methods which don't need a layout and activity stuff, create a java class and have public methods.

1) MainActivity - Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ToastClass toastClass = new ToastClass();
        toastClass.toast(getApplicationContext(), "Hey dude!!");
    }
}
```

2) ToastClass - java class

```
public class ToastClass {
    public void toast(Context context, String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context ,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Hope, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You do not instantiate activities, but starts them with an intent

```
Intent intentSecondActivity = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intentSecondActivity.putExtra("methodToStart","toast");
startActivity(intentScheduleActivity);
```

In the secondActivity read the extras and start the method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondActivity);

    String method = getIntent().getStringExtra("method");
    if (method.equals("toast"){
        toast();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you might want to study fragments.